# Congruent iff Same Remainder (CISR) Confusion

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I was reading through a proof of the following proposition:

$$a\equiv b\!\!\pmod{m}\iff (a\bmod m) = (b\bmod m)$$

i.e. $\ a \equiv b \pmod{\!m} $ *if and only if a and b leave the same remainder when divided by m*

I came across a statement that I didn't quite understand. I boxed my area of confusion below:

[image]
I am confused because I expected the inequality to be $ 0 \leq r_1 - r_2 < m$. How did they come to the conclusion that $ -m < r_1 - r_2 < m$

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: What if $r_1 = 0$ and $r_2 > 0$?

Answer (score 4):

Since
$$0\le r_2<m$$
then
\begin{align}&-m<-r_2\le0\quad \text{and since}\\
&\;\;\;0\le r_1<m\end{align}
then by adding term by term we find
$$-m<r_1-r_2<m$$

Comment: Oh! I see what they did now. So to add them, they must also add the inequality. But in this case we are adding the negative (subtracting) so we flip the inequality and then add. Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Could you explain why that implies that $r_1 - r_2 = 0$?

Comment: Since $m|(r_1-r_2)$ then $r_1-r_2=km,\; k\in \Bbb Z$ but since 
$$-m<r_1-r_2<m$$
then $r_1-r_2=0$ the only possible multiple of $m$ between $-m$ and $m$.

Comment: Oh right, its bounded by divisibility.

Comment: Yes right!${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Sami explained the inequality. I explain another way, avoiding it.

$\qquad m\mid a\!-\!b \iff a\!-\!b \in m\Bbb Z \iff  a+m\Bbb Z\, =\, b+m\Bbb Z$

$\qquad a\ {\rm mod}\ m\, $ is the least nonnegative element of $\ a+m\Bbb Z$

$\qquad b\ {\rm mod}\ m\, $ is the least nonnegative element of $\ b+m\Bbb Z.$

Being equal sets, they have equal least nonnegative elements.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2320595/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2395067/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2320595/242)