# Why are naturals < modulus equal if congruent? [uniqueness of remainder in a consecutive residue system]

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $a$, $b$, and $n$ be integers with $0 \le a,b \lt n$. If $\,a \equiv b \pmod n,\,$ i.e. $\,a-b = pk\,$ for an integer $k,\,$ then  $a=b$. Why does this congruence imply the equality?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not enough that $a,b$ are nonnegative, it is also necessary that $a,b$ are less than $n$.  With both of these conditions, then $a\equiv b$ implies that $a=b$.  The reason is that $a\equiv b$ means that $a-b$ is an integer multiple of $n$.  However, this integer multiple cannot be $n$ or greater (else $a\ge b+n$, impossible), nor $-n$ or smaller (else $a+n\le b$, also impossible).  Hence the only integer multiple of $n$ available is $0n$.

Comment: You might want to specify that it is impossible because $a \ge b+n > b$ and also $a \le b-n < 0$, violating the conditions.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: their $\rm\color{#c00}{difference}$ is a natural smaller than $\,n\,$ and divisible by $\,n\,$ so it must be $\,0,\,$ i.e.

w.l.o.g. $\ 0 \le b\le a < n\,\overset{\rm subtract\ b}\Longrightarrow\, 0\le \color{#c00}{a\!-\!b <} n\!-\!b\le\color{#0a0} n \ $ so $\ \color{#0a0}n\mid \color{#c00}{a\!-\!b}\iff a\!-\!b = 0$

**Remark** $ $ This shows the *uniqueness* part of the fact that $\,0,1,2,\ldots,n\!-\!1\,$ form a complete system of representatives for equivalence classes of $\,\Bbb Z_n = $ integers $\!\bmod n,\,$ or, equivalently, the uniqueness of the remainder in the (standard) division algorithm. The same proof works for any sequence of $n$ consecutive integers since - as above - any two elements differ by less than the extreme elements, so less than $n,\,$ so their difference is divisible by $n$ only if they are equal. An example of an alternative sequence of remainders is those having *least magnitude*, e.g. $\,0,\pm1, \pm2\pmod{\!5}$. The argument easily [generalizes](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866966/242) to any arithmetic progression whose step-size is coprime to the modulus.

[Corollary](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/811668/242)  $\ A\equiv B\pmod{\!n}\iff \underbrace{A\bmod n = B\bmod n}_{\textstyle \color{#c00}{a = b}}$

Comment: How can we show that if $a-b\leq n$ and $n\mid a-b$ then $a-b=0$? That part struggles me :/

Comment: @man An $n$-multiple $\,kn\neq 0\,$ has *greater* magnitude $\,|kn| = |k||n|\ge |n|\,$ by $|k|\ge 1\,$ by $\,k\neq 0\ \ $

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what can you conclude from there. If $k\neq0$ and $kn\neq0$ then $n=0$?

Comment: @man That $m=0$ is the only multiple $m$ of $n$ with $\,0\le \color{#c00}m <\color{#0a0} n\,$ since all other multiples $>0\,$ are $\ge n.\ $ Explicitly: the natural multiples of $n$ are $\,0,n,2n,3n,\ldots$ and there are $\rm\color{#c00}{none}$ strictly between $0$ and $n.\ $ Said more informally, an integer divides a smaller integer only when the smaller $= 0\ $

Comment: **Unique remainder** $\Rightarrow$ **unique quotient** by $\,qn+r=q′n+r\Rightarrow qn=q′n\overset{n\neq 0}\Rightarrow q=q′\ $

Answer (score 5):

The key trick here is the interplay between *magnitude* and *divisibility* — every nonzero multiple of $n$ must have a magnitude at least as large as $n$.

Symbolically, if $k \neq 0$, then $|kn| \geq |n|$.

Since integers in the same congruence class are separated by multiples of $n$, this puts a limit on how close they can be. We have

If $a \equiv b \bmod n$ and $a \neq b$, then $|a-b| \geq |n|$

The premise of the problem constrains both $a$ and $b$ to a narrow interval: they are both contained in the set $\{ 0, 1, \ldots, n-1 \}$. The largest possible difference between any two elements of this set has magnitude $n-1$. That is, for any two elements $x,y$ of this set, we have $|x-y| \leq n-1$.

So by the previous observation, the fact that $a \equiv b \bmod n$ implies that one of the following is true:

- $a = b$
- $|a-b| \geq n$

and we can rule out the second possibility because $|a-b| \leq n-1$.