# Show that any integer of the form $6k + 5$ is also of the form $3 j + 2$, but not conversely.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

Source : Burton, *Elementary number theory* (7th edition)

> Show that any integer of the form $6k + 5$ is also of the form $3 j +
>  2$, but not conversely.

**As to the $(\implies)$ part :**

$n= 6k+5$

$\implies  n = 3(2k')+5 \space $ for some $ k' \in \mathbb Z$

$\implies n = 3(2k')+3+2 $

$\implies  n = 3(2k'+1)+2 $

$ \implies n = 3j +2 \space $ with $ j = 2 k'+1 $

**As to the " not conversely part".**

It seems to suffice to find a number of the form $3j+2$ that does not leave a remainder of $5$ when divided by $6$.

Consider number $20 = 3(j)+2 $ where $j=6$.

We have also $ 20 = 6(3) +2$ .

My question is : is the counterexample method adequate and, if so, did I apply it correctly? Is stating that $20$ can be written with a remainder of $2$ when divided by $6$ sufficient to show that it cannot be written with a remainder of $5$.

Comment: Yes, because $20=6m+5$ and $20=6m'+2$ would imply $6$ divides $5-2$, which is a contradiction

Comment: A counter example is perfectly acceptable. It just takes one example to prove a statement so... throw one if you want.  However if you want to really "grok" why the converse isn't true not that $6k + 5 = 3(2k +1) + 2=3j+2$ so the converse is only true for odd values $j$.  Conversely $3j + 2 = 3(j-1) + 5 = 6(\frac {j-1}2) + 5$ only holds true if $\frac {j-1}2$ is an integer (i.e. if $j$ is odd).

Comment: By the dupe: $\,x\equiv 2\pmod{\!3}\iff x\equiv 2\,$ or $\,5\pmod{\!6},\,$ which yields a more precise claim than you seek, and clarifies the relationship between the two congruences.

Comment: I think OP is asking if it's possible that $6\mid x-2$ and simultaneously $6\mid x-5$; OP doesn't use congruences

Comment: It's best to delete this question once all is clear, since we already have too many examples of this sort (which complicates searching for answers).

Comment: Actually, on rereading you example.  I don't think you adequately showedd that $20$ *can't* be $6j + 5$.    You should $20 = 3\dot 6 + 2$ so it's of the form but to show $20\ne 6j + 6$ we must show  .... If $20 = 6j + 5$ then $15 = 6j$ and $j = \frac {15}2$ which is not an integer.... But once you do that, you have one counter example and that absolutely shows beyond all doubt that the converse is not true and you don't need to do *anything* more.

Comment: @J.W.T That too is a dupe, viz. $\,2\equiv x\equiv 5\pmod{\!6}\,$ contradicts the [uniquness of remainders](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2395053/242). $\ \ $

Comment: argj!!! I typed "It just takes one example to prove a statement " .... that was a typo.  I meant "It just takes one example to prove a statement *wrong*".   I'd like to say it was "obviously" a typo but....